# Efficient selection of turtle subsets that satisfy given condition on turtle properties

Tags: netlogo, agent, multiset

I was wondering if there is an efficient method for selecting subsets of agents that satisfy some conditions on their properties in one shot (i.e., a multi-set of agents).  I will try to explain with an example.

Let us suppose that we have three families of turtles, let's say A, B and C.
The turtles share some similar variables, such as p1, p2.

I want to efficiently determine the agent-sets A1, B1 and C1, with A1 \in A, B1 \in B, and C1 \in C, and that undergo some conditions on their variables, for example, p1 of A = p1 of B and p2 of B = p2 of C (of course this should be checked and verified for all the sets in parallel).  My  final goal is to determine the total number of agent combinations that satisfy the conditions on their variables (the cardinality of the multiset).

I know that I can do that with a series of nested "ask" command, with something like the following code:

```
;;I'm omitting for simplicity the case where  A1, B1 or C1 are empty-sets.

let counter 0    
let A1 A with [some condition on A]
ask A1 [
  let myp1 [p1] of self
  let B1 B with [p1 = myp1]
  ask B1 [
    let myp2 [p2] of self
    let C1 C with [p2 = myp2]
    set counter counter + count C1
  ]
]
;;at the end counter will contain the number of possible agent combinations
```

I was wondering if there is a more intelligent way to do that without the need to "unroll" the selection through a series of nested ask commands.

Comment: Hi! It would be a lot easier to help if you provide a [minimal & reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) , and if possible your expected results. Sometimes a few lines of code can be much more precise than a lot of explanation :) Also, please format your code as such using the formatting options in the question editor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the code you have outlined will work anything like you think it will. In NetLogo, `ask` loops through all the turtles/patches (in random order) and each one follows the instructions. So each of the A1s will create B1s and each of those will count C1s. So you will end up with two layers of double counting.

But I think all you want to do is count a common condition. If so, look at this example:

```
breed [typeAs typeA]
typeAs-own
[ var1
  var2
]

breed [typeBs typeB]
typeBs-own
[ var1
  var3
]

to testme
  clear-all
  create-typeAs 10
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set var1 one-of ["A" "B"]
    set var2 one-of ["C" "D"]
    set color red
  ]
  create-typeBs 10
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set var1 one-of ["A" "B"]
    set var3 one-of ["E" "F"]
    set color blue
  ]
  type "Number of As with value A is " print count typeAs with [var1 = "A"]
  type "Number of Bs with value A is " print count typeBs with [var1 = "A"]
  ; combine and count the condition in the combined agentset
  let both-types (turtle-set typeAs typeBs)
  type "together there are: " print count both-types with [var1 = "A"]
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think that what I obtain with the two layers of counting is what I want, because I want to know the number of possible combinations of agents that satisfy the conditions. If I'm not wrong, the  code you posted  is counting all the agents that have var1  = "A", independently from their type, or I'm missing something?

Comment: your understanding of my code is correct. But so far two of us have tried to understand your question and failed. Try giving us some fake data (eg turtle 1, type A, value 3; turtle 2, type B, value 3) and show us the set that you want to create or count.